# Different approaches to load the data from Hadoop(on-premise) to Azure Data Lake

Tags: hadoop, azure-data-lake

I have a requirement to load the data from Hadoop (which is on-premise Hortonworks cluster) to Azure Data Lake every 8 hours. Can you let me know- what the different approaches that can be tried here in implementing the solution ?

1. ADF [ We can create a pipeline activity and schedule them ]
   Anything else ?

Thanks,
Aravind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have provided high-level options at [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-lake-store-data-scenarios/). Search for: "Data stored in on-premise or IaaS Hadoop clusters".

However, there will be fine-tuning needed based on:
1. How much data you want to move, # of files, size of files etc.
    Smaller sized files will take longer to transfer.
2. Network connectivity from onprem to Azure
    If you have ExpressRoute available, you will have better experience. If you have only public internet connectivity, you will be bottlenecked by network and not the tool you use.

Thanks,
Sachin Sheth
Program Manager, Azure Data Lake.